# Remove Stack/Cabal packages and install older versions

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, build-dependencies, hackage

I'm new to Haskell and am using Stack to build a small personal project on Mac OSX. I've recently added some new build-deps to my cabal file but now when I run `stack build`, I get the following error:

```
--  While attempting to add dependency,
    Could not find package api-builder in known packages

--  Failure when adding dependencies:
      api-builder: needed (==0.11.0.0), not present in build plan (latest applicable is 0.11.0.0)
      http-client: needed (==0.4.20), 0.4.27 found (latest applicable is 0.4.20)
      http-types: needed (==0.8.6), 0.9 found (latest applicable is 0.8.6)
    needed for package: music-haskell-0.1.0.0

Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps in /Users/.../src/music-haskell/stack.yaml
- api-builder-0.11.0.0

You may also want to try the 'stack solver' command
```

When I run `stack solver` I get an error about the http-types package

```
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: music-haskell-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
next goal: http-types (dependency of music-haskell-0.1.0.0)
rejecting: http-types-0.9 (conflict: music-haskell => http-types==0.8.6)
rejecting: http-types-0.8.6, 0.8.5, 0.8.4, 0.8.3, 0.8.2................
(global constraint requires ==0.9)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

From what I understand, it looks like I already installed `http-types-0.9` but now I need `http-types-0.8.6`. I initially tried to install it manually with `$stack install http-types`, but I got the following error:

```
Error parsing targets: Specified target version 0.8.6 for package http-types does not match snapshot version 0.9
```

When I looked to see if I could do `$ stack uninstall` but it looks like that is deprecated.

How can I get rid of the snapshot/global target for `http-type`??

Comment: I have not personally used stack very much so my understanding of it is not paramount. But it looks like you need a [custom snapshot](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/wiki/Custom-Snapshot) if none of the "standard" snapshots will allow your package to build. Perhaps you are simply using the wrong snapshot, or your cabal file itself is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override a specific snapshot package in your stack.yaml file via extra-deps, e.g.:

```
extra-deps:
- http-types-0.8.6
```

Once you start including packages that have conflicting version bounds versus the snapshot you're using, you can end up running into these problems pretty quickly. My recommended solution is:

- Ask package maintainers to get their packages into Stackage so that you don't have to fiddle with the versions manually
- Stick to packages in Stackage whenever possible

You can add a package to Stackage yourself, even if you're not the author. For instructions, see [the maintainer guide](https://github.com/fpco/stackage/blob/master/MAINTAINERS.md).